# Tracking No Or Auto No For Entries With The Same Product Id and Invoice

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2000

I am trying to do a simple thing and let me make it clear first. I've a excel file and it's being loaded by an application to store excel data in a database table. It works fine and uploads data. Now I've a requirement in this scenario and the following is the excel sheet:

```
ProductId - Invoice No - Invoice Date - Price - Quantity
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:00 - 1000 - 10
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 200 - 2
102 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 20
101 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 300 - 5
102 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 200 - 5
```

See in the excel sheet, product id 101 has two entries with the same invoice no with different timing and quantities. What I want is to create a tracking no whenever there are similar invoice no and product id (Repeated invoice no and product id). Suppose, for product id 101, it has already two entries with invoice no 'Inv-1000'. So it should create two different tracking no like 1 and 2 as follows in a database table:

```
ProductId - Invoice No - Invoice Date - Price - Quantity - Auto No
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:00 - 1000 - 10 - 1
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 200 - 2 - 2
102 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 20 - 1
101 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 300 - 5 - 1
102 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 200 - 5 - 1
```

I tried to use the following code to do the above task but it creates only 1 for all the entries even for the repeated ones:

```
Do Until rs3.EOF
  If (rs4.recordCount > 0) Then
     generateId = rs3.Fields.Item("Auto No") + 1
  Else
     generateId = 1
  End If           
rs3.MoveNext
Loop
```

Seems like I am missing something. Any idea or suggestion would be appreciated in this regard. Thanks.

Note: I am validating the column names right now means if the excel sheet column doesn't match the table column, then it will not allow to upload data. Similarly, I've tried to validate row data of the excel sheet. In this case, if product id 101, invoice no 'Inv-1000' is in the table already and even with different tracking like 1, 2 already existed, then it shouldn't allow this data to be uploaded further. It looks simple but don't get to work. Struggling! Sample - Existed in the table:

```
ProductId - Invoice No - Invoice Date - Price - Quantity - Auto No
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:00 - 1000 - 10 - 1
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 200 - 2 - 2
102 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 20 - 1
101 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 300 - 5 - 1
102 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 200 - 5 - 1
```

Finally will not allow in the next upload for the above data. One more thing, keep the file in D directory and in the TextBox, write this to upload the excel file - D:\SampleExcel.xlsx

Full Code:

```
Dim recordCount As Integer 'Variable to get record count
Dim i As Integer

Private Sub btnUpload_Click()
   LoadExcelSheet
End Sub


'**Method To Upload Excel File - Starts**
Public Sub LoadExcelSheet()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

'**Record Set To Check Table Records - Starts**
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs3 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs4 As ADODB.Recordset
'**Record Set To Check Table Records - Ends**

Dim i As Long

Dim strQuery As String
Dim strQueryExistData As String
Dim strQueryMatchCol As String
Dim strQueryExcel As String

Dim strFile As String
Dim strSheet As String


Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs4 = New ADODB.Recordset

i = 0

strFile = txtFileName.Text
strSheet = "Sheet1"
con.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & strFile & ";" & "Extended Properties = Excel 12.0;"

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=.;"

con.Open

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & strSheet & "$]"
strQueryMatchCol = "SELECT m.[ProductId], m.[Invoice No], m.[Invoice Date], m.[Price], m.[Quantity]  FROM ExcelData m"
strQueryExistData = "SELECT m.[ProductId], m.[Invoice No], m.[Auto No] FROM ExcelData m"
strQueryExcel = "SELECT [ProductId], [Invoice No] FROM [" & strSheet & "$]"

rs.Open strQuery, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
rs2.Open strQueryMatchCol, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
rs3.Open strQueryExistData, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
rs4.Open strQueryExcel, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

strDate = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD") + " 00:00:00"

  Do Until rs.EOF

  Dim poNo As String
  Dim itemCode As String
  Dim grnNo As String
  Dim matDes As String
  Dim transName As String
  Dim goDown As String
  Dim vendorName As String
  Dim process As String
  Dim vendorDnNo As String
  Dim rcvQty As String
  Dim unit As String
  Dim totalAmt As String
  Dim invoiceNo As String
  Dim generateId As Integer

  generateId = 1

  '**Check Excel Column - Validation**
  If (rs.Fields(0).Name = rs2.Fields(0).Name And rs.Fields(1).Name = rs2.Fields(1).Name And rs.Fields(2).Name = rs2.Fields(2).Name And rs.Fields(3).Name = rs2.Fields(3).Name And rs.Fields(4).Name = rs2.Fields(4).Name And rs.Fields(0).Name <> "") Then

  '**Trying To Check If Product Has The Same Id and Invoice No, Then Increment By One Or Just One**
  '**Example - If Product Id 101 and Invoice No Inv-1000 Has Two Entries (Repeated), Then In The [Auto No] Column
  'Should Be Included With The Numbers 1 and 2**
  Do Until rs3.EOF
  If (rs4.recordCount > 0) Then
    generateId = rs3.Fields.Item("Auto No") + 1
  Else
    generateId = 1
  End If

  rs3.MoveNext
  Loop

  conn.Execute ("INSERT INTO ExcelData ([ProductId], [Invoice No], [Invoice Date], [Price], [Quantity], [Auto No]) VALUES ('" + Trim(rs.Fields(0).Value) + "', '" + Trim(rs.Fields(1).Value) + "', '" + Trim(rs.Fields(2).Value) + "', '" + Trim(rs.Fields(3).Value) + "', '" + Trim(rs.Fields(4).Value) + "', '" + Trim(generateId) + "')")

    i = 1

  Else

    i = 0

  End If

  rs.MoveNext

  Loop

  If (i = 0) Then
     MsgBox "Column names aren't in correct order! Please check excel sheet 1.", vbInformation, "Info"
  ElseIf (i = 1) Then
     MsgBox "Uploaded!", vbInformation, "Info"
  End If
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing

con.Close
conn.Close

Set con = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
'**Method To Upload Excel File - Ends**
```

With the above code, right now only getting the below output:

```
ProductId - Invoice No - Invoice Date - Price - Quantity - Auto No
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:00 - 1000 - 10 - 1
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 200 - 2 - 1
102 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 20 - 1
101 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 300 - 5 - 1
102 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 200 - 5 - 1
```

Comment: updated my answer, please take a look. BTW, do you mean true invoices, which shall be unique per year?

Comment: Yes, that's supposed to be. If you have time, see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390202/sum-quantity-and-price-on-specific-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refresh the content of your `rs3` recordset, to get the current data, and therefore the updated number of records, otherwise you will have always the data at the time you opened it.

As you are using a module-level variable to store the number of records, then inside your loop, after the `conn.Execute ("INSERT INTO....` you could simply use: `rs3.requery`. This is in someway equivalent as you would close and reopen the rs3 recordset before your `INSERT INTO`  statement.

**EDIT:**

Moreover, your snippet `Do Until rs3.EOF...` seems to me it should be replaced by a query like this: `SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Auto No]),0) FROM ExcelData WHERE [Invoice No]= 'Inv-1000' AND YEAR([Invoice Date]) = 2017`. You should increment that result. Please, pay attention how you compare the date, and for this selection query, strip off the time part. You will find the result inside `rs3.fields("Auto No")`. No need here to loop over the records. You should requery this recordset after every insert.

**EDIT2:**
Here an untested pseudo-code snippet, you should get the idea:

```
fmtString = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" ' you should adapt this to your need '
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & strSheet & "$]", con, adOpenForwardOnly
Do Until rs.EOF
  InvNo = Trim(rs.Fields("InvoiceNo").Value)
  InvDateTime = CDate(rs.Fields("Invoice Date").Value)
  ' separate year from full datetime, depending how the cell format is '
  InvYear = Format(InvDateTime, "YYYY")
  ' compose the query to get the Auto No '
  sql = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Auto No]),0) AS MaxNo FROM ExcelData"
  sql += " WHERE [Invoice No] = '" + InvNo + "' "
  sql += " AND YEAR([Invoice Date]) = '" + InvYear + "'"
  Set rsCheck = conn.Execute(sql) ' get the Auto No '
  AutoNo = rsCheck.Fields("MaxNo").Value + 1
  ' compose the query to store the invoices '
  sql = "INSERT INTO ExcelData ("
  sql += "ProductId, "
  sql += "[Invoice No], "
  sql += "[Invoice Date], "
  sql += "Price, "
  sql += "Quantity, "
  sql += "[Auto No]"
  sql += ") VALUES ("
  sql += "'" + Trim(rs.Fields("ProductId").Value) + "',"
  sql += "'" + InvNo + "',"
  sql += "'" + Format(InvDateTime, fmtString) + "',"
  sql += CCur(Trim(rs.Fields("Price").Value)) + ","
  sql += CSng(Trim(rs.Fields("Quantity").Value)) + ","
  sql += AutoNo 
  sql += ")"
  conn.Execute(sql) ' store the invoice '
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

IMHO it would be better if you store native data types in your table instead of all text values, then you may need here also to check the data-type of the Excel **cell** and provide the correct conversion against the **column** type of your destination table.
Sorry, but I believe the topic of the datatype conversion is too broad and it won't fit here - you may better post some new questions for that.

If you prefer to store all values as text to avoid all this boring data-type conversions, i would suggest you to store dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (24, no AM/PM) and AutoNo in a fixed length format 001..002..003 so they are at least correctly sorted.

**EDIT3:**

If your import based on the above snippet is tested and working, you can rewrite your check for already imported lines, by using the exact date time of the Excel file, as follows:

```
fmtString = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" ' you should adapt this to your need '
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & strSheet & "$]", con, adOpenForwardOnly
Do Until rs.EOF
  InvNo = Trim(rs.Fields("InvoiceNo").Value)
  InvDateTime = CDate(rs.Fields("Invoice Date").Value)
  ProdId = Trim(rs.Fields("ProductId").Value)
  ' compose the query to get the same invoice line '
  sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS ThisLine FROM ExcelData"
  sql += " WHERE [Invoice No] = '" + InvNo + "' "
  sql += " AND [Invoice Date] = '" + Format(InvDateTime, fmtString) + "'"
  sql += " AND [ProductId] = '" + ProdId + "' "
  Set rsCheck = conn.Execute(sql) ' get the current line '
  If rsCheck.Fields("ThisLine").Value = 0 Then
    ' compose the query to get the Auto No '
    ...
    ...
    conn.Execute(sql) ' store the invoice '
  End If
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

If you have enough time resolution in your data, i believe you can skip the check for the same quantity, up to you, but anyway, you should investigate the content of the Invoice Date field in your Excel file).

Comment: It looks promising @deblocker. It would be really helpul if you could provide a sample example using excel file.

Comment: The content of the Excel file shouldn't matter, the Product Id doesn't matter as well. Every time you need to insert a new record in the table, you should filter that table by Invoice No. and Invoice Date like this: `SELECT MAX ([Auto No]) FROM ExcelData WHERE [Invoice No]= 'Inv-1000' AND [Invoice Date] = 7/10/2017`. Pay attention how you compare the date.  You should increment that result (in your case you choose +1).

Comment: Did you investigated the primary key of the table? Shall be Invoice No., Invoice Date, Auto No.. Also, be sure Auto No. isn't set as Identity.

Comment: `Auto No` isn't set as identity @deblocker. Your query is just perfect. But my question is: my excel sheet has many data at a time and loads them using a form. In your query, how could I fit this - `SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Auto No]),0) FROM ExcelData WHERE [Invoice No] = 'Inv-1000' AND [Invoice Date] = 7/10/2017`? Will the `Requery` property do the work?

Comment: Thanks a lot @deblocker. You are a perfectionist. I appreciate your hard work and time. Cheers! It was a great lesson.

Comment: The last key point is not closed yet: how to avoid double insertion of the same Excel file. Please tell me if your function is actually working...

Comment: I think, I've to handle that in the same way that I handled validating the column names. Right now, I can check if the column names of the excel file matches the columns of the database table. Do you have any suggestion on that or could you provide one? What I did - I took another record set and checked if the records are the same as the excel file but didn't work perfectly. It still adds those data too. I am actually amazed at your solution and it's working perfectly for the duplicate entries now I mean creating the tracking numbers.

Comment: Yes, I am also trying to do the same using the `DateTime` field and guess this would be working. Thanks once again for your updates.