# Sum Quantity and Price On Specific Condition

Tags: sql, vb6, sql-server-2000

I am trying to do a sum of price and quantity in an excel file and store them in database table. So here it's (Trying by myself for learning) - Suppose, these are the excel file data:

```
ProductId - Invoice No - Invoice Date - Price - Quantity
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:00 - 1000 - 10
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 200 - 2 
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 4 'These should be merged with the above one as they have the same invoice, product id and date time
102 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 20
101 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 300 - 5
102 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 200 - 5
```

My requirement is if there is any product id with the same invoice and invoice date time, then it should merge those results and the output in the database table would be the following:

```
ProductId - Invoice No - Invoice Date - Price - Quantity - Auto No
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:00 - 1000 - 10 - 1
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 600 - 6 - 2 'Finally merged
102 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 20 - 1
101 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 300 - 5 - 1
102 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 200 - 5 - 1
```

So I tried it with following code validating invoice no, product id and invoice date time in a sql query:

```
str = "SELECT IIF(SUM([Price]) IS NULL, 0, SUM([Price])) AS SumPrice, IIF(SUM([Quantity]) IS NULL, 0, SUM([Quantity])) AS SumQuantity FROM [" & strSheet & "$]" & _
      " WHERE [Invoice No] = '" + InvNo + "'" & _
      " AND [ProductId] = '" + ProductId+ "'" & _
      " AND [Invoice Date] = '" + strDate + "'"

Set rs = con.Execute(str)
```

But in WHERE clause, I get these error - **Data type mismatch in criteria expression**.

After the error message, I did use only the invoice no with product id to check if that works and it did (For the invoice 'Inv-1000' and product id 101) like this but rest of the excel data aren't loaded -

**Excel Data:**

```
ProductId - Invoice No - Invoice Date - Price - Quantity
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:00 - 1000 - 10
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 200 - 2 
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 4 
102 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:30 - 400 - 20
101 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 300 - 5
102 - Inv-1001 - 7/11/2017 10:30 - 200 - 5
```

**Output in the database table:**

```
ProductId - Invoice No - Invoice Date - Price - Quantity - Auto No
101 - Inv-1000 - 7/10/2017 10:00 - 1600 - 16 - 1
```

**Note:** One more thing, if the sum is done, I again would like to check or validate the sum shouldn't be entered twice for that particular invoice no, product id and invoice date (I've already done the validation in the sample project but for the sum, will the validation work?).

Here is the full code (Use a TextBox and keep the excel file in D directory, finally write this in the TextBox - D:\SampleExcel.xlsx):

```
Dim recordCount As Integer 'Variable to get record count
Dim i As Integer

Private Sub btnUpload_Click()
   LoadExcelSheet
End Sub

'**Method To Upload Excel File - Starts**
Public Sub LoadExcelSheet()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

'**Record Set To Check Table Records - Starts**
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs3 As ADODB.Recordset
'**Record Set To Check Table Records - Ends**

Dim i As Long

Dim strQuery As String
Dim str As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim strQuery2 As String
Dim strQuery3 As String

Dim strFile As String
Dim strSheet As String


Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset

i = 0

strFile = txtFileName.Text
strSheet = "Sheet1"
con.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & strFile & ";" & "Extended Properties = Excel 12.0;"

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Demo;Data Source=.;"
con.Open

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & strSheet & "$]"
strQuery2 = "SELECT ProductId, [Invoice No], [Invoice Date] FROM DataExcel"
strQuery3 = "SELECT ProductId, [Invoice No], [Invoice Date], [Price], [Quantity] FROM DataExcel"

rs.Open strQuery, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
rs2.Open strQuery2, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
rs3.Open strQuery3, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

strDate = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD") + " 00:00:00"

If (rs2.recordCount > 1) Then
  MsgBox "Few or all records already exist! Check excel file."
ElseIf (rs.Fields(0).Name <> rs3.Fields(0).Name Or rs.Fields(1).Name <> rs3.Fields(1).Name Or rs.Fields(2).Name <> rs3.Fields(2).Name Or rs.Fields(3).Name <> rs3.Fields(3).Name Or rs.Fields(4).Name <> rs3.Fields(4).Name) Then
  MsgBox "Column names don't match! Please check excel file."
Else
    Do Until rs.EOF
    Dim InvNo As String
    InvNo = rs.Fields(1).Value

    Dim AutoNo As String
    Dim AutoNo2 As Integer

    Dim ProductId As String
    ProductId = rs.Fields(0).Value

    Dim ProductId2 As Integer
    ProductId2 = rs.Fields(0).Value

    Dim InvoiceDate As String
    InvoiceDate = Trim(rs.Fields(2).Value)

    Dim Price As String
    Price = Trim(rs.Fields(3).Value)

    Dim Quantity As String
    Quantity = Trim(rs.Fields(4).Value)

    strDate = Format(InvoiceDate, "YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss")

    'This is what I am doing - Checking the same invoice no, product id and invoice date.
    'If any found in the excel file, then sum up the quantity and price
    str = "SELECT IIF(SUM([Price]) IS NULL, 0, SUM([Price])) AS SumPrice, IIF(SUM([Quantity]) IS NULL, 0, SUM([Quantity])) AS SumQuantity FROM [" & strSheet & "$]" & _
          " WHERE [Invoice No] = '" + InvNo + "'" & _
          " AND [ProductId] = 101" & _
          " AND [Invoice Date] = '" + strDate + "'"

    Set rs = con.Execute(str)

    Quantity = rs.Fields("SumQuantity").Value
    Price = rs.Fields("SumPrice").Value

    'Here is the trick - Initially passed the excel file data to verify
    'and checking if any product id exists with the same invoice number in the database table
    str = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Auto No]),0) AS AutoNo FROM DataExcel" & _
          " WHERE [Invoice No] = '" + InvNo + "'" & _
          " AND [ProductId] = '" + ProductId + "'"

    Set rs2 = conn.Execute(str) 'Gets the auto number

    AutoNo2 = rs2.Fields("AutoNo").Value + 1 'Increments the number by one if any duplicate exists
    AutoNo = AutoNo2 & ""

    str = "INSERT INTO DataExcel (" & _
          "[ProductId], " & _
          "[Invoice No], " & _
          "[Invoice Date], " & _
          "Price, " & _
          "Quantity, " & _
          "[Auto No]" & _
          ") VALUES (" & _
          "'" + ProductId + "'," & _
          "'" + InvNo + "'," & _
          "'" + InvoiceDate + "'," & _
          "'" + Trim(Price) + "'," & _
          "'" + Trim(Quantity) + "'," & _
          "'" + AutoNo + "')"
    conn.Execute (str) 'Finally stores data with tracking or serial numbers

  rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing

con.Close
conn.Close

Set con = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
'**Method To Upload Excel File - Ends**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBH, i didn't tried to run your query, so i can't say anything about your error. But, this query here:

```
strQuery = "SELECT [Invoice No],[invoice Date],[ProductId],"
strQuery += "SUM(Price) AS Price,SUM(Quantity) as Quantity"
strQuery += " FROM [" & strSheet & "$]"
strQuery += " GROUP BY [Invoice No],[invoice Date],[ProductId]"
```

will produce following rows:

```
Inv-1000    2017-07-10 10:00:00 101 1000 10
Inv-1000    2017-07-10 10:30:00 101  600  6
Inv-1000    2017-07-10 10:30:00 102  400 20
Inv-1001    2017-07-11 10:30:00 101  300  5
Inv-1001    2017-07-11 10:30:00 102  200  5
```

so, you can iterate over this rows to import your invoices.

About the check for already imported data:

The check should behave like before, you can anyway skip to import the same data twice, just use the same query for the check - because we are grouping by unique invoice date, also the uniqueness of the whole grouping is granted as well.

IMHO, i believe, the only difference here by using this kind of grouping, will be that you need to check also if the sum of the quantities in the Excel file is the same as the one already existing in the import table. Then, you can decide either to update the sum of the quantity with the new value, skip the import or raise an error.

Comment: Come on @deblocker. You got me again and this was simple enough. Thanks once again for your time and effort. By the way, simple things make more confusion though :p

Answer (score 1):

Try to create sql functions which get conditions and calculate results.
SQL Functions is the best way to provide dynamic results for different kind of outputs.

Comment: AFAIK, functions return one value at a time. So will this work in the above scenario @Qaiser Mehmood? Thanks for the reply.